# Difference between number of TCP Connections and number of HTTP Transactions

Tags: python, centos

For my college project I am trying to develop a python based traffic generator.I have created 2 CentOS machines on vmware and I am using 1 as my client and 1 as my server machine. I have used IP aliasing technique to increase number of clients and severs using just single client/server machine. Upto now I have created 50 IP alias on my client machine and 10 IP alias on my server machine. I am also using multiprocessing module to generate traffic concurrently from all 50 clients to all 10 servers. I have also developed few profiles(1kb,10kb,50kb,100kb,500kb,1mb) on my server(in /var/www/html directory since I am using Apache Server) and I am using urllib2 to send request to these profiles from my client machine. Next my guide wants me to monitor number of TCP Connections and HTTP Transactions being generated during traffic generation session. Firstly, I can't clearly differentiate between these 2 entities. To my understanding, TCP Connections is the TCP Session-SYN/ACK/FIN,etc. and HTTP Transaction is the number of HTTP methods-GET/POST/DELETE/HEAD,etc. Is this correct? If NO then what is correct answer to this question? And secondly, how to monitor these 2 entities using python?

```
    '''
Traffic Generator Script:

 Here I have used IP Aliasing to create multiple clients on single vm machine. 
 Same I have done on server side to create multiple servers. I have around 50 clients and 10 servers
'''
import multiprocessing
import urllib2
import random
import myurllist    #list of all destination urls for all 10 servers
import time
import socbindtry   #script that binds various virtual/aliased client ips to the script
response_time=[]    #some shared variables
error_count=multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
def send_request3():    #function to send requests from alias client ip 1
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler3)    #bind to alias client ip1
    try:
    tstart=time.time()
    for i in range(myurllist.url):
    x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
    opener.open(x).read()
    print "file downloaded:",x
    response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
    error_count.value=error_count.value+1
def send_request4():    #function to send requests from alias client ip 2
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(socbindtry.BindableHTTPHandler4)    #bind to alias client ip2
    try:
    tstart=time.time()
    for i in range(myurllist.url):
    x=random.choice(myurllist.url[i])
    opener.open(x).read()
    print "file downloaded:",x
    response_time.append(time.time()-tstart)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
    error_count.value=error_count.value+1
#50 such functions are defined here for 50 clients
process=[]
def func():
    global process
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=send_request3))
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=send_request4))
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=send_request5))
    process.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=send_request6))
#append 50 functions here
    for i in range(len(process)):
     process[i].start()
    for i in range(len(process)):
     process[i].join()
    print"All work Done..!!"
     return
start=float(time.time())
func()
end=float(time.time())-start
print end
```

Comment: Answer to 1 is: "true", answer to 2: count how many times you connect and count how many times you issue GET/POST/DELETE/HEAD with your chosen method.

Comment: Hello@Antti Haapala I have appended my code here. Can you guide me how do i count number of TCP Connections and number of HTTP Transactions here? Ok for HTTP Transactions I will use a global counter that increments after every "opener.open(x).read()" line. But how do I get value of TCP Connections here?

Comment: If you know what the code is doing, you can determine those numbers, but I guess you guide wants you to use a network sniffer. It can tell you the number of TCP connections and, being aware of HTTP, it can also tell you the number of HTTP requests. In any case, I don't see a question related to programming here.

Comment: urllib2 does not support keepalive conns, every HTTP request is a new connection